# Can animals think intuitively?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, animal-cognition, intuition

We agree that human beings have intuition - "the ability to understand something instinctively, without the need for conscious reasoning." And the *level* of intuition varies from people to people. 
Can animals think intuitively?

Comment: Welcome to CogSci! Though I appreciate that you specified a definition of intuition, I think this question is nonetheless impossible to answer from a cognitive science POV in its current form. We obviously do not have a measure of consciousness in animals, so we cannot know if animals have intuition by the given definition. You might find a better forum for it on the Philosophy SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a philosophical question than a cognitive science question. If the quality is improved and it is made more specific it might be on topic at our Philosophy site.